# how can i install jruby alongside ruby

Tags: jruby, jrubyonrails

i first installed jruby using the sudo apt-get install jruby command, which succeeded but it did gave me 1.5.6 version when i wanted a later version. So i uninstalled it and used rvm install jruby command and i was able to install jruby version 1.7.19 but after installing it, my ruby applications,which were funtioning right started producing errors complaining of missing gems like mysql2 gem missing,run bundle install. i run bundle install but nothing i did seemed to help, i was getting nowhere.
When i asked for the ruby version, i was receiving the jruby version instead, its lyk jruby over shadowing ruby,,,, So i decided to uninstall jruby, reinstall ruby and now ruby is functioning as well as before.
Can anyone help me with the ubuntu commands which can help me install jruby alongside ruby, so that both work well without any errors???
Am requesting for serious help please

Answer (score 5):

I usually prefer rbenv over rvm for running multiple versions of Ruby on the same machine. Here is sample install/usage steps:

1. Install rbenv `git clone git://github.com/sstephenson/rbenv.git ~/.rbenv`
2. Install ruby-build `git clone git://github.com/sstephenson/ruby-build.git ~/.rbenv/plugins/ruby-build`
3. Modify your .bashrc `echo 'export PATH="$HOME/.rbenv/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.bashrc
   echo 'eval "$(rbenv init -)"' >> ~/.bashrc`
4. Restart your shell
5. Install rubies. e.g. `rbenv install jruby-1.7.20`
6. Rehash (create new rbenv shims. You'll need to run this anytime you install a gem that adds a command) `rbenv rehash`

   - You can list the Ruby versions available to install with `rbenv install -l`
   - You can set the default global ruby version with `rbenv global jruby-1.7.20`.
   - You can also pass "system" instead of an installed Ruby if you want the default to be the OS installed version of Ruby.
   - You can change Ruby version on the fly with `rbenv shell 1.9.3-p551`

See here (https://github.com/sstephenson/rbenv#command-reference) for a lot more detail and documentation.

**Edit**: I was assuming you're using Ubuntu, hence the edit of .bashrc. If you're using another OS you may need to change that to .bash_profile

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for that answer. I have also found out that it is soo possible to have jruby and ruby installed concurrently using rvm. After installing the various versions or languages say ruby and jruby, only the default language and version is running in the terminal as current so you have to run the command 'rvm list' to show you the various installed versions after which you run 'rvm use language-X.X.XX' say rvm use jruby-1.7.20.1 to make jruby-1.7.20.1 run as the current in that terminal.
You can also run another version in a different terminal concurrently but please note, you have to run the command rvm use every time you open up a new terminal, else you make that version default.